# How to check for keyboard notification outside of my ios apps?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to check for keyboard notification show/hide outside of my ios apps. I tried to run keyboard notification in the background, did not work.

I expected to switch to a different app or homescreen and my ios app should detect whether keyboard is shown or hide when i'm outside my ios apps.

Comment: What is the functionality you're attempting to achieve? It's well known that iOS employs strict [sandboxing methodologies](https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/); you're unlikely to be able to retrieve anything outside the context of your own application. You may be able to work around this slightly by providing the user with a [custom keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html) (provided your users are actually *using* it), tough to say if it'd pass App Review without knowing more about your use case.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible since app do not communicate with each others by default. just like in the previous answer, it's because of sandboxing. If you could tell what you want to achieve, we might be able to help